# Can't access MariaDB from go-sql-driver even I can access it from mariadb-client

Tags: mysql, go, mariadb

I've installed MariaDB 10.3 with the Galera cluster on Debian 10 Linux server.

I've created a user **ueda** with grant all privilege as follows:

```sh
MariaDB [koshinto]> show grants for 'ueda'@'localhost';
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for ueda@localhost                                                                                                              |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO `ueda`@`localhost` IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*923D7E4A76755E0B4924C29266AFA3E675D990DC' WITH GRANT OPTION |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

I can log in with user ueda and issue sql command as follows:

```
ueda@scw-a:~$ mariadb -u ueda -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 169
Server version: 10.3.27-MariaDB-0+deb10u1 Debian 10

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]> use koshinto
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
MariaDB [koshinto]> select * from test;
+----------+------------------------------+
| bindid   | bind                         |
+----------+------------------------------+
| kerokero | {"kero":"kerokero","aho":20} |
+----------+------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

But, from following go code,

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    log.SetFlags(log.Lshortfile)
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "ueda:somepassword@/koshinto")
    defer db.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    } else {
        _, err := db.Query("select * from test") //
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }
    }
}
```

Even same user and password on the same server, error occurs as "Access denied".

```sh
ueda@scw-a:~$ go run mysql.go 
mysql.go:18: Error 1045: Access denied for user 'ueda'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: Note: Never use `go run <file>.go`

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the right connect string? Not sure if you've obscured something from your code snippet but make sure to use `ueda:somepassword@protocol(ip:port)/koshinto` which would most likely be `ueda:somepassword@tcp(localhost:3306)/koshinto` when you run on the same machine

Comment: The fact that he got access denied from the server suggests it did contact the server. All error codes in the 1000's are returned by the server. If it failed to reach the server, it would have been a client error code in the 2000's.

Comment: Thank you poppe. I've tried with ``tcp(localhost:3306)`` but result was same ``1045: Access denied``